# Uploading tomcat application throws SSL Exception

Tags: exception, tomcat, ssl, web

I have implemented a web application in NetBeans using Tomcat 7. This application is working properly in localhost. I am trying to upload this application on a web hosting site and it seems to be uploaded properly. The problem is that at some point, it throws the following exception and i can't figure out what is the problem. I have read a few posts with the same problem but the problem still exists.

root cause

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm" "read")
java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:555)
java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1302)
java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:706)
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSystemSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:255)
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSystemSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:366)
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSystemSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:204)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createSystemDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:82)
org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(SystemDefaultHttpClient.java:118)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:466)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createHttpContext(AbstractHttpClient.java:286)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:851)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
org.apache.jena.riot.web.HttpOp.execHttpGet(HttpOp.java:148)
org.apache.jena.riot.stream.LocatorURL.open(LocatorURL.java:47)
org.apache.jena.riot.stream.StreamManager.openNoMapOrNull(StreamManager.java:124)
org.apache.jena.riot.stream.StreamManager.open(StreamManager.java:81)
org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.open(RDFDataMgr.java:725)
org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.open(RDFDataMgr.java:714)
org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.parse(RDFDataMgr.java:649)
org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:211)
org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:184)
org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:122)
org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:113)
org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.RDFReaderRIOT.read(RDFReaderRIOT.java:77)
com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:247)
com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.readModelWorker(FileManager.java:378)
com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.loadModelWorker(FileManager.java:309)
com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.loadModel(FileManager.java:261)
MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:127)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:271)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:306)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:166)
```

Just to mention that in the line of my class that is shown in the stack trace (MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:127)) there is just a url to a page.

Any ideas would be appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

The Tomcat server you are uploading to is running under a security manager which is not allowing Tomcat to read the `ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm` system property. You need to request your hosting provider to adjust the security policy to allow Tomcat to read this property.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information! So there is nothing i can personally do to fix that right?

Comment: Unless you can switch the outgoing connection from https to http I don't see a way around this.